# How to get a calender to put date in input textbox in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, mootools, datepicker

I have a web application that uses HTML and Javascript. I want to create a textbox that allows to user to enter in a keyword and submit it. I also want a little calendar icon next to the textbox so the user can click on it to popup a calendar to select a date as the keyword, and then submit that.

I have tried to implement DatePicker but couldn't get it working. It keeps saying that DatePicker is undefined.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools-core-1.4.3-full-compat.js"></script>

<script src="Source/Locale.en-US.DatePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Source/Picker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Source/Picker.Attach.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Source/Picker.Date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Source/datepicker_dashboard/datepicker_dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input name='date_toggled' type='text' value='' class='date date_toggled' style='display: inline' />
<img src='calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif' class='date_toggler' style='position: relative; top: 3px; margin-left: 4px;' />
```

Javascript

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
new DatePicker('.date_toggled', {
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_dashboard',
        allowEmpty: true,
        toggleElements: '.date_toggler'
    });
});
```

What can i try to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

add an id to your 'date_toggler' image

```
<img src='calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif' id='my_date_picker' class='date_toggler' style='position: relative; top: 3px; margin-left: 4px;' />
```

then script..

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
    new DatePicker('my_date_picker', {
        pickerClass: 'datepicker_dashboard',
        allowEmpty: true,
        toggleElements: '.date_toggler',
        onSelect: function(date){
            document.id('date_toggled').set('value', date.format('%s');
        }
    }
}
```

check the options and methods in the docs at https://github.com/arian/mootools-datepicker/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Also on the basis that you are getting a DatePicker is undefined message, I would do as Swippen suggests, and check the path to your Javascript scripts, and that they are all being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this in JS have a look at http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/timestamp.shtml

For doing it in JQuery have a look at http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePicker.html

Answer (score 0):

First make sure all the javascripts are loaded correcly and that the paths are correct. (Use firebug or similar to see if they have loaded all the javascripts).

Then if all seems to load correctly you can use debug and breakpoints at the "new DatePicker.." row and use immediate window or such to see if date picker exists.